# upload script for webpage

Tags: php

so i am trying to make an upload script for my webpage and i cant seem to make it work. upon trying to upload a file, the address bar says "webpage.com/upload.php" but fails to load the page or upload the file. php.ini has uploads enabled with a 10240M (10G) upload max size. the goal is just a simple upload script that wont accept 2 files with the same name. here is the flawed code. comment out the css and the include header/footer if you want to try it. i left those in incase it did affect something.

On the Webpage (located at /var/www/content/file.php) :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kaiocraft</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php $logo="/logo.png"; include("/var/www/header.php"); ?>
        <form action="/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>file to upload:</p>
            <input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload">
            <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit">
        </form>
    <?php include("/var/www/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

in the PHP script (located at /var/www/upload.php) :

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/var/www/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["filetoupload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<p>a file with that name already exists</p>";
    uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 1) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filetoupload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)) {
    echo "<p>uploaded successfully</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>error. please try again</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

and a blank folder at /var/www/uploads to save to.

and yes i am aware that this is a super risky and insecure way to do it but it has to accept ANY file type up to 10G.

EDIT:
when i comment out

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<p>a file with that name already exists</p>";
    uploadOk = 0;
}
```

in the php script it works, however i can overwrite it with a file of the same name.

Comment: "do you see any flaws in this?" I assume you ask this for a reason. So instead of letting the community go on some scavenger hunt for something why don't you tell us what is wrong, what the error message is you are getting, what your debugging attempts turned up and where you are stuck.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. i have changed it.

Comment: Errors? Something? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Why do you tag it as "Javascript"? I don't see any javascript.

Comment: `uploadOk = 0;` should be `$uploadOk = 0;` (note the `$` sign).

Comment: tagged as javascript in error but didnt notice til posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
basename(S_FILES["filetoupload"]["name"]);
```

should be

```
basename($_FILES["filetoupload"]["name"]);
```

You have S instead of $

also, set post_max_size in php_ini, not only upload_max_filesize

Here is your upload script rewritten (it works, i've tested)

```
<?php
// show errors, disable this on production server
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$target_dir = "/var/www/inovision.ro/web/ddns/up/";
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["filetoupload"]["name"]);

if(!file_exists($target_file) && isset($_FILES["filetoupload"]["error"]) && $_FILES["filetoupload"]["error"] == 0) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filetoupload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    echo "<p>uploaded successfully</p>";
}
else if(file_exists($target_file)) {
     echo "<p>a file with that name already exists</p>";
}
else {
    echo "<p>error uploading</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: i have corrected both of those issues however it still fails to upload

Comment: can you look in the error logs? or enable error reporting (in php.ini or on upload.php). What is the error it gives?

Comment: Also, move your upload folder outside of public folder or protect it with .htaccess, otherwise your app will have serious problems. you can serve the uploaded files with php for security reasons.

Comment: i do not know how to turn on error reporting as i am new to this and i will .htaccess protect it but i wish to get it working first.

Comment: i've updated my answer with a working upload script

Comment: thank you so much andreibaboi, as well as all of you who helped. =D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your upload folder exists, and is writable by the web user on your system

For instance on Ubuntu the user is www-data, and permission should be 775.

Comment: done that and it is still not working. and it is a ubuntu